# is this possible to run and control an exe file from another one?

Tags: c#, resources, exe

imagine we have an exe file named "worker.exe" that has a button in it named "Run", now I want to create a secondary application named "host" that has "worker.exe" in resources. 
when the host runs on a button click it runs "worker.exe" and should hit the button "Run".
(problem is simplified. I have an exe file that I do not have access to its internal methods. I want to create a licensing service for that to get a username and password an then run that exe file)
is this possible? if yes so how?

Comment: Even if you had this licensing service, what's to prevent people from just running Worker.exe on their own, bypassing your licensing?

Comment: i am going to place that "worker.exe" in applications Resouce, so as i know people can not access this directly, right?